# Overclocking doesn't take effect on raspberry os 64 bits

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-lite, overclocking

I have a rpi4 8gb, running lots of dockers, and im having a heavy use of my CPU and I would like to oc it t 2GHz but I can't, I have set the over voltage and arm_freq but it doesn't work, I check the file where the current cpu and the max cpu and its always 1.5 GHz, It cannot go over it.
running the latest raspberry pi os lite 64 bits with the latest firmware and updates

I have put

over_voltage=6

arm_freq=2000

gpu_freq=750

Comment: Are you aware that this is probably going to brick your pi quite rapidly?

Comment: Where did you set those parameters?

Comment: @PMF I have a good cooling and I have seen that having the right PSU (official one is the one I have) and good temps, is good to go.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev /boot/config.txt